# Fire off multiple synchronous threads

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0

I'm not sure if this is a silly question as I don't know much about threads, but is it possible to fire off multiple synchronous threads at the same time, and wait for all to complete before acting? If it is how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Parallel.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634.aspx).
This will execute the supplied actions in parallel and return when all are finished.

Comment: this sounds like the simplest method

Answer (score 3):

Certainly the simplest way is to use .NET 4.0 's Task Parallel Library (TPL).

e.g.

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, x => 
// Do this in Parallel.
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x)
);
```

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/concurrency/bb964701

Answer (score 2):

> ut is it possible to fire off multiple synchronous threads at the same time, and wait for all to complete before acting?

"synchronous threads" is an oxymoron, they don't exist.

Of course you can start multiple threads and wait for them to complete (`Thread.Join(otherThread)`)

> If it is how do you do it?

Very rarely. Always use as few threads as possible. They are expensive.

Make sure you know about the ThreadPool and (Fx4) the Tasks library, TPL

Comment: thanks, i'm not too bothered about the performance, it is a rare ocurrence and the only reaosn I am doing it is because I must make multiple calls to a web service at once

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do *anything* at the same time, let alone fire threads :) (you can fire them rapidly one after the other though, although it is possible that a thread will start before the last one is fired).

As for waiting for them all before continuing, you can use the Join method, which waits for a thread to end before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you'd do with the construct like below,

```
public class MultipleThreqadTest
{
    private readonly Thread[] threads;
    private readonly object locker;
    private int finishCounter;
    private readonly AutoResetEvent waitEvent;

    public MultipleThreqadTest()
    {
        threads=new Thread[10];
        for(int i=0;i<0;i++)
            threads[i]=new Thread(DoWork);
        finishCounter = threads.Length;
        waitEvent=new AutoResetEvent(false);

    }
    public void StartAll()
    {
        foreach (var thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Start();
        }
        //now wait for all worker threads to complete
        waitEvent.WaitOne();
    }


    private void DoWork()
    {
        //Do Some Actual work here, you may need to lock this in case you are workin on some shared resource
        //lock(locker)
        //{

        //}

        //Check if all worker thread complets
        if(Interlocked.Decrement(ref finishCounter)==0)
        {
            this.waitEvent.Set();
        }
    }

}
```